# Reactjs SyntaxError: Unexpected token '...'. Expected a property name. in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile-safari

I am encountering an error in older version of safari.  I am using react v16.2.0 and I am viewing our web app in Safari using iPhone5SE v11.1.2

Please see attached screenshot on the link

[Safari Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGAfS.png)

Comment: Which safari version? The spread operator requires ES6 support https://caniuse.com/?search=es6

Comment: @AndrewParks it's running v11.1.2